# How to make backspace key in Windows 7 Explorer get me to parent folder instead of going back in history?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows7: Changing Backshift Shortcut in Explorer back to upwards?](https://superuser.com/questions/368375/windows7-changing-backshift-shortcut-in-explorer-back-to-upwards)

In Windows XP, `Backspace` (aka `←`) key leads you to the parent folder, but in Windows 7 it just goes back in history. How do I make it work like in the old days?

Comment: @PatrickS. The download link for HTGback is down in that question. I edited a working one in the answer below

Comment: @nixda: You should have edited the original answer as well. This one is a duplicate and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can be done with an application

- download & extract [HTGback](http://www.softsea.com/review/HTGBack-Backspace.html)
- place a shortcut in your Startup folder
  [image]

#### Can also be done with an AutoHotKey script

- create a texfile, copy the code below into it and save it as myscript.ahk
- download [portable AutoHotKey](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=217) (needed only once for compiling the script)
- open *Ahk2Exe.exe*, browser to your myscript.ahk and press compile
- create a shortcut to the new .exe in your startup folder

  ```
  #IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
  Backspace::
     ControlGet renamestatus,Visible,,Edit1,A
     ControlGetFocus focussed, A
     if(renamestatus!=1&&(focussed=”DirectUIHWND3″||focussed=SysTreeView321))
     {
      SendInput {Alt Down}{Up}{Alt Up}
    }else{
        Send {Backspace}
    }
  #IfWinActive
  ```

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8955/make-backspace-in-windows-7-or-vista-explorer-go-up-like-xp-did/)