# How to make backspace key in Windows 8 Explorer get me to parent folder instead of going back in history? [revamped]

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, autohotkey, keymap, backspace

Posting [the same question from another user](https://superuser.com/questions/529043/how-to-make-backspace-key-in-windows-7-explorer-get-me-to-parent-folder-instead), but for windows 8 instead.

In Windows XP, Backspace (aka ←) key leads you to the parent folder, but in Windows 8 it just goes back in history. How do I make it work like in the old days?

The answer given from K.A (very complete & simple btw, kudos to him) doesn't work on Windows 8. I get an error message saying

```
    Error at line 1.

    Line Text: ÿÞ#
    Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.

    The program will exit.
```

How can it be getting to work On Windows 8?

Comment: A little search about the error [shows](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/113987-error-at-line-1-with-unicode/) that you're using an older version of AHK, that doesn't recognize the Byte Order Mark the error is telling you of. Either save as ANSI or UTF-8 or use a more up-to date version.

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned by [Doktoro Reichard](https://superuser.com/users/228536/doktoro-reichard) this can be due to using old version of [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/).  Always use AutoHotkey and its documentation from
   http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official
   website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is
   outdated and you may have some problems using them!
2. If that does not helps try to run script from administrator account.

*Note: in windows 7 & 8, ALT 'up arrow' performs the function that the backspace key use to do.  While its not the backspace, at least is has *zero net effect* on memory and cpu, where as running a program is an added cost.